# Laravel - calling method without user request

Tags: php, laravel

I have my own library class which is designed for gathering data from external web sites (uses curl). This class has constructor which receives parameters (e.g. URL, xpaths) and method updateDatabase. How to pass parameters to constructor and call method updadeDatabase in app internally? This method should be fired e.g. two times per day without user request (using the cron) So I don't want insert this code in controller and create appropriate route. How to do this?

```
class Source
{
     public function __construct(Http $http, array $params)
     {
        ...
     }

     public function updateDatabase()
     {
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Please include your Laravel version. Laravel 5 comes with it's own cron scheduler internally for this kind of thing

Comment: I am using Laravel 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to create an artisan command. This gives you access to to run your code within the Laravel framework from the command line (or cron job).

All the information you need for creating an artisan command can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands).

Basically, inside the command's `fire()` method you would do something like:

```
public function fire() {
    $source = App::make('Source'); // or however you instantiate your class
    $source->updateDatabase();

    // output a message to the command line
    $this->info('All done.');
}
```

Your command can also take arguments and options from the command line, if you need to pass those in.

The documentation linked above will tell you all you need to know.